# Display items below Input field Selectize.js

Tags: selectize.js

I am relatively new to using Selectize and was wondering if it was possible to display the selected item(s) below the search field.. something similar to this...
[Desired Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nBJI.png)

My existing code is as follows:-

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-12">
                    <select class=form-control asp-for=CountryIds asp-items=Model.Countries data-val-required-hidden></select>
                </div>
```

JS

```
let countryPage = {
    setup:{

        let selectize = $("#CountryIds").selectize({
            placeholder: "Or search for another country",
            highlight: true,
            openOnFocus: false,
            closeAfterSelect: true,
            render: {
                item: function (item, escape) {
                    return ('<div class="btn btn-country">' + item.text + ' <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill icon-c"></i></div>');
                }
            },
            onItemAdd: (value, $item) => countryPage.bindCountry(value, $item),
            onChange: (value) => {
                $("#CountryIds").valid();
            }
        })[0].selectize;

        selectize.$control.on('mousedown', function () {
            selectize.close();
        });

        selectize.on('type', function (e) {
            if (selectize.$control_input.val().length <= 1) {
                selectize.close();
            }
        });

        $(".selectize-input .btn-country").each(function () {
            countryPage.bindCountry($(this).data("value"), $(this));
        });

        selectize.on('item_add', function (value) {
            let valueWithoutPrefix = value.replace('country-', ''); 
            let $item = $('[data-destination][value=\'' + valueWithoutPrefix + '\']');

            if ($item.length > 0) {
                $item.prop('checked', true);
            }
        });

        selectize.on('item_remove', function (value) {
            let valueWithoutPrefix = value.replace('country-', ''); 
            let $item = $('[data-destination][value=\'' + valueWithoutPrefix + '\']');

            if ($item.length > 0) {
                $item.prop('checked', false);
            }
        });

        $('[data-destination]').on('change', function (e) {
            let countrysSelectize = $("#CountryIds")[0].selectize;
            let $this = $(this);
            let value = "country-" + e.currentTarget.value;

            if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                countrysSelectize.addItem(value);
                countryPage.bindCountry(value, $this);
            }
            else {
                countrysSelectize.removeItem(value);
            }
        });
    },
    bindCountry: (value, $item) => {
        let countrysSelectize = $("#CountryIds")[0].selectize;
        $item.find("i").click(function () {
            countrysSelectize.removeItem(value);
            countrysSelectize.focus();
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried creating a second selectize below the original and populating it but this didn't work.

I've also searched extensively online but no-one seems to have a solution.